# await return addeventlistener can't be null

Tags: javascript, async-await, return

commerce shop and I render dynamically  a site with details product I want make corosuel but when im trying add a second await after return is impossible i've tried them method but I get this error In console "addEvent Listener cant be null"

```
const ProductScreen = {
  render: async () => {
    
    const request = await parseRequestUrl();
    
    const product = await getProduct(request.id);
    if (product.error) {
      return `<div>${product.error}</div>`;
    }
    return `
    <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel__item carousel__item--visible">
      <img src="${product.image}" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__item">
      <img src="${product.image2}" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__item">
      <img src="${product.image3}" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel__actions">
      <button id="carousel__button--prev" aria-label="Previous slide"><</button>
      <button id="carousel__button--next" aria-label="Next slide">></button>
    </div>
  </div>


  
    `;
   
  },

} 



export default ProductScreen;
```

and them is slider

```
 let slidePosition = 0;
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel__item');
  const totalSlides = slides.length;
  
  document.
    getElementById('carousel__button--next')
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      moveToNextSlide();
    });
  document.
    getElementById('carousel__button--prev')
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
      moveToPrevSlide();
    });
  
  function updateSlidePosition() {
    for (let slide of slides) {
      slide.classList.remove('carousel__item--visible');
      slide.classList.add('carousel__item--hidden');
    }
  
    slides[slidePosition].classList.add('carousel__item--visible');
  }
  
  function moveToNextSlide() {
    if (slidePosition === totalSlides - 1) {
      slidePosition = 0;
    } else {
      slidePosition++;
    }
  
    updateSlidePosition();
  }
  
  function moveToPrevSlide() {
    if (slidePosition === 0) {
      slidePosition = totalSlides - 1;
    } else {
      slidePosition--;
    }
  
    updateSlidePosition();
  };
```

Can u give me any advice how do i suppose to do this?

Comment: Your error is saying you are trying to bind the events before it is rendered to the page. Without seeing how ProductScreen render  and the code  relate to each other, it is a guessing game on our part.

Comment: Probably relevant: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198)

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait until the first await gives a response before applying a second await.

Comment: `await` *is* what is waiting before continuing with the code.

Comment: Maybe try adding the EventListeners after the HTML is returned @Michal Widawski